# Update query too slow on big PostgreSQL table

Tags: database, postgresql, database-performance, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to improve speed of simple UPDATE query, but it is taking between 0.7-1.5s for one row, which is too slow.

```
UPDATE users SET firstname = 'test' WHERE userid=2120;
```

Here is explain:

```
Update on users  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=331) (actual time=0.068..0.068 rows=0 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=331) (actual time=0.039..0.040 rows=1 loops=1)
    Index Cond: (userid = 2120)
Trigger updatemv: time=727.372 calls=1
Total runtime: 727.487 ms
```

Total database size is 20GB and about 60 tables. I have problems with table 'users' which has 1.36 million rows. Table 'users' has 36 columns (4 bigint, 5 integers, 10 character varying (from 32 to 255) and other are boolean fields), half of them are null for a lot of rows. Also there are 6 indexes on 'users' table. Database is hosted on Amazon RDS db.m4.2xlarge with 8 vCPU, 32 GB RAM and 100 GB SSD. Version of PostgresSQL is 9.3.

I tried to VACUUM ANALYZE tables and that helped, but it is still too slow.

I read about upgrading RAM/CPU, tuning database in postgresql.conf, creating separated tablespace for big table, etc. But I am not sure what is the best approach for handling big tables with million rows.

With current trend my table will grow to 20 milion rows in next 12 months, so I need durable solution.

Any advice how to improve speed of UPDATE query on big tables are helpful.

Comment: I'm missing something . . . 20 GB for 1.36 million rows is l5k per row.  And only spread among 36 columns?  Those are mighty big columns, especially if most are `NULL`.

Comment: `Trigger updatemv: time=727.372 calls=1` You have triggers on this table, or other tables with FKs that refer to it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Database has about 60 tables with total size of 20GB. I have problem with the biggest table 'users' which has 1.36 milion of rows. I think there are no big columns. It is 4 bigint, 3 integer, 15 character varying (from 32 to 255), 5 timestamps, and boolean fields.

Comment: Checking the obvious: could there be locks by other modifying transactions?

Comment: You seem to have a materialized view which is being updated when this table changes. The update of the view seems to be triggered by a trigger named updatemv.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I had materialized view refresh trigger, when I removed it, update is taking just 0.123 ms instead of 727.487 ms, 6000 times faster :) I will try to organize materialized view different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @joop I resolved my problem. I had trigger to refresh materialized view. When I removed it, update query is taking just 0.123 ms instead of 727.487 ms, 6000 times faster.

I have organized materialized view different way.

Answer (score 0):

Tuning the parameters in postgresql.conf can have a huge impact and it's free, so I would start there.  The default values are way too low.